# Why hex conversion results are different with Python and Lua?

Tags: python, lua, integer, hex, sha256

My Python program do hash encoding that need to convert a sha256 code to int, like this:

```
>>> int("9f5133d8933398a525bc39d6721c1684696c45e877cd49016f222a50571284ff", 16)
72061215364900703654959674737822274980132311264471434449381308563657411691775
```

which also equals with the result from [www.binaryhexconverter.com](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com)

But, it is different when I need to transfer my work to Lua:

```
> tonumber("9f5133d8933398a525bc39d6721c1684696c45e877cd49016f222a50571284ff",16)
8008009611964744959
```

Additional, I find that if input is a shorter code, their results are the same.

Python:

```
>>> int("9f5133d89", 16)
42766384521
```

Lua:

```
> tonumber("9f5133d89", 16)
42766384521
```

Can someone explain the reason for this difference? And is there any way to help me get the same results as Python in Lua program?

I use Python 3.9 and Lua 5.3

Thank you.

Comment: python:   If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, 
or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in the given base. 
The literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded by whitespace. 
The base defaults to 10. Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.
Base 0 means to interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.

Comment: Lua can not handle a number that is that long (64 bytes)

Comment: What response did you get from Lua when you contacted them? A quick Google search reveals to me that Lua is (by default) limited to 64-bit integer values. Python has no such limitation

Comment: @Nifim I think you mean 64 bits

Comment: @Fred 256 bits it is sha256

Comment: Your value is 121 bits but your question is why is the representation different in Lua and Python and that has been explained to you. If you want Python to emulate Lua then do a bitwise *AND* with 0xffffffffffffffff

Answer (score 2):

Lua 5.3+ numbers are either 64-bit doubles or 64-bit integers. The former can only store integers up to 2^53 - 1 while the latter can only store integers up to 2^63 - 1. Your number is way too big for that, thus you get an overflow and the wrong number.

To store your number, simply keep it as a string. You can use a bytestring if you want it to be more space-efficient.

Python integers on the other hand are big integers; that is, there is no size limitation, arbitrary large integers can be parsed and represented precisely, thus everything works as expected for you.